# How to pull bulk text out of file and paste it into another file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Ok so i have a few files which contains emails and passwords. I want to make a single file of only the passwords, of all the files, without altering the originals. Each line is structured as so:

```
example@example.com:password
```

(there is no space between either the email or the password from the colon)

I was trying to figure out how to grep the file and pipeline the text into a new file but im not so sure on how to write the command.
Please help thankyou.

Comment: Do the usernames `:` in them?

Comment: no the colon is just an arbitrary seperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no colon characters in the email addresses, For a bunch of files, let's call them `files*.txt`:

```
cat files*.txt | sed -e 's/[^:]*://' > all-passwords.txt
```

Should do it.

- `cat files*.txt` - prints all lines to STDOUT
- `sed -e 's/[^:]*://'` - replace everything up to the first ':' on the line with "nothing"
- `> all-passwords.txt` - create/overwrite a file called all-passwords.txt
- `>> all-passwords.txt` - If you were to use `>>`, it will only create or append to the file, not overwrite it.

**Notes**:

- If you have ':' characters in only the passwords, this will still work.

Comment: You don't need the `cat`. `sed ... files*.txt > ...` would work fine.

Comment: Thanks muru, I understand that.  I'm not going for an optimum solution, rather one that helps explain what steps in the pipeline do.

Comment: (of which one step is entirely unnecessary).

Comment: if it replaces everything up to the colon will it change the original files?

Comment: @EvanFoulk it will not.  It's just changing the lines that were printed and passed into the pipeline.  The original files stay in tact.

Comment: okay thank you very much the sed command worked perfectly!

Comment: now i have a lot of files i want to run this command with how would i append them instead of overwriting the file each time?

Comment: @EvanFoulk use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: Also it seems the orginal file had some errors where the colon is a semi colon where in the command do i add the semicolon

Comment: @EvanFoulk as long as there are not semicolons in the email addresses or passwords, you can simply add another  `| sed -e 's/[^;]*;//'`.  Notice I changed the two colons to semi-colons in that snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f2- file1 file2 > output
```

- `-d:` tells `cut` that the fields are separated with `:`, and
- `-f2-` tells `cut` to output all fields from the second onwards.

Comment: due to errors in the original file this gave me a much cleaner output if i put   -d;: will that also do the same for semicolon seperated password or should i put -d; -d:

Comment: @EvanFoulk `cut` only supports a single separator character. You'd be better off with `sed` if multiple characters can be separators.

Comment: @EvanFoulk there are countless ways to do things like this, the tools here are just a couple of ways.  Keep in mind you can also re-process the 'all-passwords.txt' using these same tools.  Also, if you put ';' in the command line, make sure you surround it with single quotes.  It has special meaning unless it's quoted like that.